# Stomped cant insert value in a static map container

Tags: c++

For some reason I cant insert a value into a static map container. I am using VS2010 and here is my code

```
Header File
class MyClass
{
    static std::map<std::string,std::string> config_map;
    static void SomeMethod();
};

Cpp File
std::map<std::string,std::string> MyClass::config_map ;

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
...
config_map.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("dssd","Sdd")); //ERROR
}
```

This is the error that I get

`Unhandled exception at 0x0130ca29 in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.`

I also tried `config_map["str"] = "something"` . It seems that I cant insert anything in it. Any suggestions ?

This breakpoint lands in xtree

```
_Pairib _Linsert(_Nodeptr _Node, bool _Leftish)
        {   // try to insert node at _Node, on left if _Leftish
        const value_type& _Val = this->_Myval(_Node);

        _Nodeptr _Trynode = _Root(); //Breakpoint lands here
        _Nodeptr _Wherenode = this->_Myhead;
        bool _Addleft = true;   // add to left of head if tree empty
        while (!this->_Isnil(_Trynode))
            {   // look for leaf to insert before (_Addleft) or after
            _Wherenode = _Trynode;
            if (_Leftish)
                _Addleft = !_DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->comp,
                    this->_Key(_Trynode),
                    this->_Kfn(_Val));  // favor left end
            else
                _Addleft = _DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->comp,
                    this->_Kfn(_Val),
                    this->_Key(_Trynode));  // favor right end
            _Trynode = _Addleft ? this->_Left(_Trynode)
                : this->_Right(_Trynode);
            }
```

Comment: How do you call your SomeMethod() ? Are you sure the exception occurs at the `.insert` call? The exception text shows that there is some NULL pointer being dereferenced. It looks mostly like the error is elsewhere.

Comment: I am definitely sure it happens at insert since I am stepping through statements

Comment: The Somemethod() is called by another static method

Comment: Let me guess: that static method is called from constructor of some object that is declared as a global variable (or is a static member of some class)?

Comment: Yes its being called by a static property of some other class. However If i try to add to a static vector it doesnt have any issues

Comment: try to declare `config_map` in a function as a static variable, then return it through that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the map is not properly initialized by the moment you are writing into it. Instead of making the map `static`, you can make an object of your `MyClass` to be a global variable or a static member. Then initializing the map in the constructor of the class should work.

Initialization order of static objects across different .cc files (I guess this is the case: the write is performed from another module) is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. could you explain what you mean that. Also I am just surprised at the initializing order. I declared a static vector just above the map which is also static and the vector gets initialized and the map doesnt

Comment: I just suggested another approach to initialization of your map: define your class like `class MyClass { public: std::map<...> config_map; MyClass() { config_map.insert("A", "B"); }};` and then declare a static instance of the class: `MyClass global_myclass;`. Here the object will be constructred properly, and you will be able to access the map through `myclass.config_map` (although not from initialization of another static objects).

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, it looks like you are looking at the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

What happens: the order of initialization for static objects in different translation units isn't guaranteed. You hit the case, where it is the order you don't want.

Comment: I am just surprised at the initializing order. I declared a static vector just above the map which is also static and the vector gets initialized and the map doesnt

Comment: @MistyD Even if random code shuffling is making the problem go away, it wont guarantee that the problem doesn't show up on another platform, another compiler, another version of your current compiler, or in stormy weather. ;) Look at the next FAQ entry for a solution similar to what Inspired recommends.