# Resolving a static initialization order fiasco

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to resolve a static initialization order fiasco. This is in reference to my previous post  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501363/stomped-cant-insert-value-in-a-static-map-container/16501532?noredirect=1#comment23689493_16501532). I have a static method that populates the properties of a static container. Now one class in my project has a static property that retrieves a value from that static method. The problem is the static property of the class is called before the static method is initiated. My question is how can I resolve this issue.
The code example is given below

```
//This is the code that has the static map container which is not initialized when 
//its queried by the OtherClass::mystring
Header File
class MyClass
{
    static std::map<std::string,std::string> config_map;
    static void SomeMethod();
};

Cpp File
std::map<std::string,std::string> MyClass::config_map ;

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
...
config_map.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("dssd","Sdd")); //ERROR
}
```

Now some method is being called by the following porting

```
 Header File
    class OtherClass
    {
        static string mystring;
    };

    Cpp File
    std::string OtherClass::mystring = MyClass::config_map["something"]; // However config_map has not been initialized.
```

Could anyone explain whats the best method to resolve such a fiasco ? I have done some reading but I still cant understand it. Any suggestions or code example would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: In most cases, making your data function-static instead of class-static should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a function and declare `config_map` as a static inside it

```
class MyClass {
...
  static std::map<std::string,std::string> & config_map() {
    static std::map<std::string,std::string> map;
    return map;
  }
};

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
...
config_map().insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>("dssd","Sdd"));
}

std::string OtherClass::mystring = MyClass::config_map()["something"];
```

now map is guarantee to be initialized.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. For this method to work am I also suppose to have a static member as such `static std::map<std::string,std::string> config_map;`

Comment: I never got a chance to use a static local varible.

Comment: you can remove the static member, just use this function to access `config_map`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just one question you defined the map variable as static in a method. So when the method `config_map()` ends doesnt the scope of the static variable also end. How is the variable still there ? Any suggestions or links on in method static variables explaination

Comment: Hope [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/43-file-scope-and-the-static-keyword/) helps.

Comment: ^ , the lifetime of function static variable behave the same as a lifetime of a class static variable. they get destructed when your program ends.